# Git: Copy source code to new branch without history

Tags: git, branch

I have 2 branches in git repository: `common` and `myown`.

I want to copy the source from one branch to another branch but I want to see in history of `common` branch only commits related to feature migration (from `myown` to `common`).

Is it possible to copy the source without the history or is a new repository required?

In addition it can be necessary to merge from `common` to `myown` and after some changes copy source back as new commit (and only as that commit - without history of all other commits as I said previously).

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you want but it sounds a bit like `git rebase` and choosing `squash` for the intervening commits.  With this you can squash a series of commits into a single commit.  However, the last line about copying source back to a new commit sounds odd.  If you create multiple distinct commits with the same modifications this can be confusing.

Comment: It's possible (`git merge --squash`) but seems like a really bad idea. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to hide "kitchen" of development process. So I need very clear history for branch with releases. I am trying to give access to specific branch which contains only releases and not intermediate stuff.

Comment: Do you realize how git's DAG looks like?

Comment: I guess answer is in my update already. If anybody can comment it or suggest something - you are welcome!

Comment: @maxim, if you find an answer to your own question, please _do_ post it as an answer. You can get upvotes for it and later accept it if no better answer shows up, which would tell people and the stackoverflow software that the problem is resolved.

Comment: --Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Comment: @Maxim 8 hours elapsed. Please post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks that I have figured out how to do it. For example we have branch `myown`.
And we need to create new one empty (without history):

```bash
git checkout --orphan common
```

Now we need to add files:

```bash
git add .
```

And commit all:

```bash
git commit -m "Initial"
```

You can see in log only this commit (not all made in myown branch).
Now we can checkout myown branch and continue work:

```bash
git checkout myown
```

We can do multiple commits in own branch (similar to regular work):

```bash
git commit -m "feature1"
...
git commit -m "feature2"
```

Now we have committed both and log contains both. We need to copy that to `common` branch and name it "release1"

```bash
git checkout common
git merge --squash myown
git commit -m "release1"
```

That's all for my first part of question.
Also it is easy to commit to `common` repository (small change/fix for example related to release1 itself). You can make regular merge to put code back to `myown` branch.

Answer (score 37):

I found a faster way that can be used:

```
git checkout <branch> -- .
```

This will replace the content of the currently checkouted branch by the content of the `<branch>`.

This doesn't copy `<branch>` commit history.

If you just want to checkout only some files just replace the `.` with the file paths from `<branch>`.

EDIT: I found out that this will only replace current files and it will not delete files that are not on the `<branch>`.

It is then better to run `rm -rf` before doing the checkout.

Comment: this is amazing way to avoid endless conflict resolution for long lasting branches

Comment: the commits are still visible from "Version Control" tab on IntellijIdea

Answer (score 0):

Clean the folder but keep hidden files/folders:

```
mkdir ../delete
mv * ../delete
rm -rf ../delete
```

Copy source code from *branch*:

```
git checkout <branch> .
```