# Sign old commits, but untracked files block rebase

Tags: git

im trying to sign some old commits on branch **testing** due to new company policy.
But due to .gitignore being added in later commits i get some .idea files that block the rebase because the files are untracked.

im using this command to sign them.
`git rebase --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S' -i --root`

Do i need to edit the old commits?
I tried copying the branch as per this question [Git: Copy source code to new branch without history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790014/git-copy-source-code-to-new-branch-without-history)
But the Pull Request cant compare or merge because they have unrelated histories, even with the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag

How can i either sign the old commits without untracked files or copy the branch without the unsigned commit history`?

Comment: Could you just stash the untracked changes?